# JAX RS Client API interceptor

Tags: java, jax-rs, aop, interceptor

Is there a way to add a header into the request via interceptors,but not via explicitly setting a header, when JAX RS Client API is used:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("someUrl").path("somePath").request().get();
```

In AOP way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a [`ClientRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html):

```
@Provider
public class MyClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "value");
    }
}
```

And register it in your [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MyClientRequestFilter.class);
```

Comment: can I register this filter globally?

Comment: @Alexandr, how many clients would you like to create? Be aware that `Client` instances are heavy-weight objects and the [documentation advises to create only a small number of `Client` instances in the application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html). And don't forget [closing your `Client` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html#close--) before disposing it.

Comment: If you have [CDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic.htm) enabled in your project, my advise is to produce a `Client` instance using [producer methods or producer fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm). To close the client, use a [disposer method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv003.htm).