# Remove filter from JAX RS client

Tags: java, jax-rs

I needed to add an authorisation header to all outgoing requests from the client, and I added a `ClientRequestFilter` as instructed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33020290/3551365) answer.

Now I want to change the properties of the filter I created. I tried to re-register a new copy of the filter but that didn't work. I tried to look through the available methods of the Client object but didn't find anything like de-register or remove.

Sample Code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new ClientObjectMapperProvider());
AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter = new AuthTokenFilter(authTokenService, authConfig);
        client.register(authTokenFilter);
//make some requests


//In another method in another class
AuthTokenFilter newFilter = new AuthTokenFilter(authTokenService, newConfig);
client.register(newFilter);

//make more requests
```

When I send requests after registering the new filter, I want the auth header to be different according to the new config, but that's not happening.

On further investigation it seems that the client object will not register an object if another of the same type is already registered. Still haven't found a way to de-register though.

Comment: *I tried to re-register a new copy of the filter but that didn't work* where's the code?

Comment: @nullpointer I can't share the whole thing because it's spread across multiple files and there's a lot of it, but I have edited to include the basic idea.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this eventually?

Comment: I just had to create a new client for running each test. Basically client.close(), client = new Client()...

Answer (score 2):

Creating Client instances is quite heavyweight so you don't want to do that very often, hence it makes sense that you are caching and reusing the client instance.

If you simply wish to have a separate authentication filter per targeted endpoint then registration doesn't have to be done on the client instance. Before you can actually talk to anything you need to create a WebTarget (which represents a concrete endpoint to which you are to communicate) Once you've created your WebTarget you can register your filter with that.

Configuring webtarget's can also be fairly heavy weight ([see here](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/how-to-use-jersey-client-efficiently)) 
but it does mean that you can spawn (and cache) different authentication filters per targeted host.

If you are wanting to dynamically reconfigure your client/webtarget based on some edited configuration (e.g. properties file/configuration REST endpoint) then you 
can simply have a cache of WebTarget/Client instances which you regenerate from scratch when the configuration changes. (You need to remember to call `client.close()` before discarding any old client instance)

Comment: That was my first idea too, but since I'm calling quite a lot of different endpoints in various methods I didn't want to change all of them - that would defeat the whole point of using a filter - to avoid copy pasting the same code all over the place.